# Is it possible to bypass pygeos when using geopandas sindex?

Tags: python, geopandas, r-tree

I am currently using Geopandas, and I need to search for the k-nearest neigbour efficiently in a data frame. According to the [documentation](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.sindex.html), the implementation of sindex depends on wether or not pygeos is available. Unfortunatly, this change the api for [nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.nearest.html) method, which only supports k-nearest when using [rtree](https://rtree.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class.html#rtree.index.Index.nearest) implementation instead of pygeos.

Is there a way to force geopandas to bypass pygeos and use rtree instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From [docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#using-the-optional-pygeos-dependency):

You can still toggle the use of PyGEOS when it is available, by:

- Setting an environment variable (`USE_PYGEOS=0/1`). Note this variable is only checked at first import of GeoPandas.
- Setting an option: `geopandas.options.use_pygeos = True/False`. Note, although this variable can be set during an interactive session, it will only work if the GeoDataFrames you use are created (e.g. reading a file with `read_file`) after changing this value.